# Is 'double checked locking pattern' good for std::mutex in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I often encounter with the design of this thread-safe structure. As the following *version1*, one thread may call `foo1::add_data()` rarely, and another thread often call `foo1::get_result()`. For the purpose of optimization, I think it can use an atomic for applying double checked locking pattern(DCLP), as *version2* showed. Is there other better design for this situation? Or could it been improved, for example accessing atomic with `std::memory_order`?

**version1**:

```
class data {};
class some_data {};
class some_result {};

class foo1
{
public:
    foo1() : m_bNeedUpdate(false) {}

    void add_data(data n)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);

        // ... restore new data to m_SomeData

        m_bNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    some_result get_result() const
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
            if (m_bNeedUpdate)
            {
                // ... process mSomeData and update m_SomeResult

                m_bNeedUpdate = false;
            }
        }
        return m_SomeResult;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex  m_mut;
    mutable bool        m_bNeedUpdate;
    some_data           m_SomeData;

    mutable some_result m_SomeResult;
};
```

**version2**:

```
class foo2
{
public:
    foo2() : m_bNeedUpdate(false) {}

    void add_data(data n)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);

        // ... restore new data to m_SomeData

        m_bNeedUpdate.store(true);
    }

    some_result get_result() const
    {
        if (m_bNeedUpdate.load())
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
            if (m_bNeedUpdate.load())
            {
                // ... process mSomeData and update m_SomeResult

                m_bNeedUpdate.store(false);
            }
        }
        return m_SomeResult;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex          m_mut;
    mutable std::atomic<bool>   m_bNeedUpdate;
    some_data                   m_SomeData;

    mutable some_result         m_SomeResult;
};
```

Comment: You need atomic access to `m_SomeResult` in addition to `m_bNeedUpdate`, otherwise you have a race (thread 1 starts copying `m_SomeResult`, thread 2 interrupts it and starts an update). Assuming `m_SomeResult` is integral, just make it atomic; otherwise, you are IMHO better off with a standard read-write lock (I think it can be done with the double-check lock, but it's complicated and isn't worth it).

Comment: If only one thread call `foo2::get_result()`, was it still race condition?

Comment: Probably not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that version 2 isn't thread safe, at least
according to C++11 (and Posix, earlier); you're accessing
a variable which may be modified without the access being
protected.  (The double checked locking pattern is known to be
broken, see
http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf.)
It *can* be made to work in C++11 (or non-portably earlier) by
using atomic variables, but what you've written results in
undefined behavior.

Comment: Does it work(not break) by using atomic variable? Sorry I can't understand.

Comment: Do you mean make `m_SomeResult` as an atomic? Another question, if there was only one thread calling `foo2::get_result()`, was `m_SomeResult` need to been atomic?

Comment: @cbel No.  It's `m_NeedUpdate` that needs to be atomic, so that all accesses to it are "ordered" relative to what precedes and follows.  And that is true as long as there is more than one thread which accesses this variable, and any thread modifies it.

Answer (score 1):

I think a significant improvement (in terms of code size as well as in terms of simplicity and performance) could be achieved by using a 'read-write lock' which allows many threads to read in parallel. Boost provides [`shared_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) for this purpose, but from a quick glance it appears that [this blog article](http://oroboro.com/implementing-readwrite-locks-portably/) implements the same kind of lock in a portable manner without requiring Boost.

Comment: I have my doubts about the implementation in the article you cite; you really need a condition variable to avoid race conditions.

Comment: @JamesKanze It may well be that the code in the article is defective, I didn't actually take the time to review it as closely as is necessary for multi-threaded code. If you think that the article is giving bad advice, feel free to suggest alternatives. I just grabbed the first Google hit for boost-less implementations which don't look totally insane.

Comment: I've not analyzed it in detail either, but in general, when you need to control access to multiple variables, you need a conditional variable.  And the more or less canonical implementation uses conditional variables.  (Why the article doesn't use the canonical implementation, I don't know.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I wasn't even aware of there being a 'canonical' implementation, it would certainly make a nice addition to this answer. :-)

Comment: I've always considered the implementation in _Programming with POSIX Threads_ (ISBN 0201633922) to be pretty much the canonical implementation.  It's for Posix threads, but the C++ threading model is based on the Posix threading model.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you're calling get_average quite often, have you considered calculating average only based on numbers that you haven't 'seen'? It would be O(n) instead of O(n^2).

It would be something like

```
average = (last_average * last_size + static_cast<double>(
           std::accumulate(m_vecData.begin() + last_size, m_vecData.end(), 0))) /
           m_vecData.size();
```

It should give you satisfying results, depending on how big your vector is.

Comment: Sorry I didn't say clean, the calculation of average is not important. I should correct that it's some task but not get average. I will edit.